# JavaScript sorting a string of integers

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, parsing

So I have this form which takes in a string of numbers that needs to be split at each semi colon and space. Afterwards, it sorts the numbers and returns the sorted list.

For some reason, when I click on the button, it does not post the value in the text box.

Can anyone help me solve my problem please! Thank you.

Edit 1: Added the name to the form and added the fieldset

```js
function sort() {
  var allNumbers = document.mainForm.mainSet.numbers.value.split("; ");
  allNumbers.parseFloat;
  for (var i = 0; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
    allNumbers[i] = parseInt(allNumbers[i], 10);
  }
  allNumbers.sort();
  document.mainForm.mainSet.sorted.value = allNumbers.toString();
}
```

```html
<form name="mainForm">
<fieldset name="mainSet">
  Enter Numbers:
  <input type="text" class="text" name="numbers" />
  <br/>
  <br/>Select Option:
  <select name="sortOption" id="dropDown">
    <option value="Ascending" class="select">Ascending</option>
    <option value="Descending" class="select">Descending</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <br/>Sorted Numbers:
  <input type="text" class="text" name="sorted">
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Sort Numbers" id="submit" onclick="sort()" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you look at your console output (F12)?

Comment: What elemental debugging steps have you taken?  Have you look at what allNumbers is using a `console.log()` statement or in the debugger?  Your first order of business is to track line by line through your code and figure out where it is going wrong.  Always look at the console for errors.  Insert debug statements to output variables you need to see (or learn how to step through your code in the debugger).  Your answer would be obvious here with simple debugging/troublshooting techniques which all developers must learn.

Comment: @JBaczuk i just check the console output and it gave me an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" for the line where i declare the var allNumbers

Comment: @Harbus That's because you have to find the DOM elements by class or ID using document.getElementById('numbers'), for example.

Comment: @Harbus, typically that sort of information (error message) is what should be provided when initially asking the question. Afterwards, it's good to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28334868/edit) to provide that detail instead of adding a comment. SO works different from forums and aims to be an useful QA site without all the chit-chat. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. This will order the number by what you have selected in your `sortOption` field.

```js
var order;
function sort() {
  order = document.getElementById("dropDown").value;
  var allNumbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value.split("; ");
  var nums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
    nums.push(parseInt(allNumbers[i], 10));
  }
  nums.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a > b)
      return order == 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    else
      return order == 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
  });
  document.getElementById("sorted").value = nums.toString();
}
```

```html
<form name="mainForm">
  <fieldset name="mainSet">
    Enter Numbers:
    <input id="numbers" type="text" class="text" name="numbers" />
    <br/>
    <br/>Select Option:
    <select name="sortOption" id="dropDown">
      <option value="asc" class="select">Ascending</option>
      <option value="desc" class="select">Descending</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>Sorted Numbers:
    <input id="sorted" type="text" class="text" name="sorted">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Sort Numbers" id="submit" onclick="sort()" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Well you seem to have fixed my problem! I am currently looking into all the changes to make sure I fully understand it, because I hate not knowing how something works. Thank you very much.

Comment: The assignment of 'order' should be outside the sort function, since it's a loop invariant.  For the purposes of speed, in fact, the function passed to sort() should be a function variable chosen on the basis of the value of the selected order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any elements named "mainForm" or "mainSet" in the HTML.  Likewise, I'm not entirely sure what the purpose of "allNumbers.parseFloat;" is, either, since that's not how to invoke a function, and parseFloat isn't a member of Array.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. You've explained what's wrong, but haven't told how to fix it.

Comment: "allNumbers.parseFloat;" isn't a thing.  The JS parser doesn't know what to do with it.  It should come out.  The response from imtheman is closer to the target.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sort() {
    function asc(a,b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
    
    function desc(a,b)
    {
        return b - a;
    }

    var allNumbers = document.getElementById("numbers").value.split("; ");
    var nums = [];
    var order = document.getElementById("dropDown").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < allNumbers.length; i++) {
        nums.push(parseInt(allNumbers[i], 10));
    }
    nums.sort((order == 'asc') ? asc : desc);
    document.getElementById("sorted").value = nums.toString(',');
}
```

```html
<form name="mainForm">
  <fieldset name="mainSet">
    Enter Numbers:
    <input id="numbers" type="text" class="text" name="numbers" />
    <br/>
    <br/>Select Option:
    <select name="sortOption" id="dropDown">
      <option value="asc" class="select">Ascending</option>
      <option value="desc" class="select">Descending</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>Sorted Numbers:
    <input id="sorted" type="text" class="text" name="sorted">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Sort Numbers" id="submit" onclick="sort()" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: The split should probably use /\s*;\s*/ instead of "; " as well, but I was concerning myself with the awkward sort function in the earlier answer.